# How to remove blue underline on text in Chrome - CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I was wondering how to remove blue underline on text, i tried it with inspector but i found nothing to change it. Firefox and Opera looks fine, but Chrome not... I wasted my time...

Go to http://bksn.mx/TAC/ **Rendering > Interior** use your mouse over the first thumbnail, then it shows a tooltip showing a text with blue underline. I needed a help how to remove blue underline with Chrome browser?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but Chrome not... I wasted my time...

... it took me 5 seconds... maybe you should learn how to use the inspector better? Remy has a nice [screencast on debugging tools](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/debugging-tools/) :o)

**for your question:**

on your `style.css` file

under line 21 add `text-decoration: none;` to the `a:hover, a:active` style

[image]

**By the way**, your `tiptip.css` is mentioned but not found:

[image]

Comment: Also, i saw your screenie, i deleted tiptip.css... now i removed <link> tag for this css. Thanks for showing me this interesing tool! i will try it when i have chance!